# semantic ui table fixed height

Tags: semantic-ui

Is there a way to create a semantic UI table with a fixed height? If there is 1 item in the table, the rest of the list would be empty but the table element would not shrink. All examples on semantic UI don't show anything similar to what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Did you find out the solution @SegFaultDev ?